# Export crystal report to pdf in Asp.Net MVC5 app on Arvix hosting serve

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

In my Asp.Net MVC5 project Crystal reports working well on local IIS server, but when I published it on my Arvixe server the export to pdf functionality only refreshing the page and do nothing else.

When I configure Elmah.axd for error logging it throws an error:

> Method not found: 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.ISCRExportOptions.get_ExportOptionsEx()

Comment: Did you make sure to deploy the correct assemblies?

Comment: @mason  yes, I check All assemblies many times All the methods which i used for Crystal reports in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine and this assembly deployed

Comment: Have you ask your hosting provider to setup Crystal Report for you? If your CR has not been setup, then it wont work. Make sure that your hosting provider support Crystal Report